# Neo4j: Speed up Relationship matching by property inequality

Tags: performance, indexing, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 3.0.5.

My query looks as follows:

```
MATCH (cd:ConnectionDay)-[c:Connection]->()
WHERE id(cd)= { id } AND c.departure <= { departure }
RETURN c
```

In my graph, the number of `Connection` relations is very high and I'm looking for a way to speed up the retrieval. Is there a way to create an index for the departure property?

I'm using the Embedded Java API anyway, so solutions that aren't using Cypher are ok, too.

Comment: It seems to me that it is necessary to make the properties to be indexed in a separate node.

Comment: @stdob Do you think, the overhead of one additional node + one additional relation would be worth it?

Comment: I think this is not a problem. All in the spirit of of graph theory.

Answer (score 2):

*Aside: It is not recommended that you use native neo4j IDs to find nodes, as after a node is deleted its native ID can be reused. It is safer to add your own property to store an ID that you know is permanently unique.*

Neo4j does not currently support indexing for relationship properties. If you want to use indexing, you can alter you data model to "reify" your `Connection` relationships as nodes. For example, your new data model would look something like this:

```
(cd:ConnectionDay)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(c:Connection {departure: 123})-[]->()
```